# Rails HABTM finder_sql ignored when scope added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord, arel, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a custom joins table setup to manage a HABTM relationship. I have written custom SQL for the `:finder_sql` option because my joins table is a polymorphic relationship. This works fine for the base case, but it appears that my `:finder_sql` is being completely ignored when I add an additional scope to the reference.

The joins table looks like this:

```
Table "public.question_template_joins"
        Column        |          Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Description
----------------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------
 question_template_id | integer                |           | plain    |
 template_owner_id    | integer                |           | plain    |
 template_owner_type  | character varying(255) |           | extended |
```

The HABTM relationship is defined on the models like this:

```
finder_sql = proc { <<-SQL
  SELECT DISTINCT question_templates.* FROM question_templates
  INNER JOIN question_template_joins ON question_templates.id = question_template_joins.question_template_id
  WHERE question_template_joins.template_owner_id = #{id}
    AND question_template_joins.template_owner_type = '#{self.class.table_name}'
SQL
}
has_and_belongs_to_many :question_templates, finder_sql: finder_sql
```

If I make a call like this, everything works fine:

```
> template = SurveyTemplate.first
> template.question_templates
```

Correct query made:

```
  QuestionTemplate Load (5.2ms)   SELECT DISTINCT question_templates.* FROM question_templates
 INNER JOIN question_template_joins ON question_templates.id = question_template_joins.question_template_id
 WHERE question_template_joins.template_owner_id = 4
 AND question_template_joins.template_owner_type = 'survey_templates'
```

The case that breaks is if I chain a scope onto the call like this:

```
class QuestionTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, where(active: true)
end

> template = SurveyTemplate.first
> template.question_templates.active    # added active to call
```

**Incorrect query actually made:**

```
QuestionTemplate Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "question_templates".* FROM "question_templates" 
  INNER JOIN "question_templates_survey_templates" ON "question_templates"."id" = 
  "question_templates_survey_templates"."question_template_id" WHERE 
  "question_templates_survey_templates"."survey_template_id" = 4 AND 
  "question_templates"."active" = 't'


ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  relation 
"question_templates_survey_templates" does not exist
```

It has reverted back to trying the default HABTM lookup.

**Why is `ActiveRecord`/`AREL` ignoring my `:finder_sql` when a scope is added?**

**What can I do to correct it?**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you still have the issue, I think a few details are missing for me to give a confident answer. Based on the information you have provided, there are a couple of things that you have done that are likely confusing the ActiveRecord logic.

1. You have created a join table between QuestionTemplate and SurveyTemplate that does not follow Rails convention. Rails, by default, assumes that the join table name is `question_templates_survey_templates`, but it looks like you would like to use a different join table named `question_template_joins`. If you want to use your join table, you are going to have to specify that when you declare your HABTM (e.g. `has_and_belongs_to_many :question_templates, finder_sql: finder_sql, join_table: "question_template_joins"`). Your `:finder_sql` could probably be simplified/reduced with this option.
2. I do not believe Rails is smart enough to connect options between inversely related HABTM classes. While you have provided a `:finder_sql` for a SurveyTemplate to find its QuestionTemplates, you will probably need a provide a different `:finder_sql` for a QuestionTemplate to find its SurveyTemplates.

I have my doubts about #2 because I don't fully understand your desired relationship between QuestionTemplate and SurveyTemplate. If you want Rails to "Just Work", switching to the Rails default join table (`question_templates_survey_templates`) will probably solve your problem. However, given that you have specified a `template_owner_type` column in your custom `question_template_joins`, I assume you have assigned a certain level of importance to that owner type; if so, I am not sure a Rails default HABTM will be able to accommodate your need(s).

There are certainly ways to work with/around ActiveRecord, but without knowing the exact desired relationship between QuestionTemplate and SurveyTemplate, it is difficult to given any concrete answers.